# magnific-popup lightbox does not lock position on mobile phone

Tags: mobile, popup, magnific-popup

I am using magnific-popup lightbox and the known issue is when you are on a mobile phone... the  screen doesn't lock the scroll like in destkop.. anyone came across a solution?